# I formatted my external drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-7, delete

So, I just completely switched from Windows 7 to Ubuntu, no Windows left.

I deleted all the old data (~200GB) from my external hard drive (1TB) because I wanted to start completely new. I took a look at the details of the drive and saw that it used 600MB space but there was nothing on it, so I right clicked and pressed format.

I chose Ext4.

Now the drive (D:) is lost and it's not shown anymore. Where did it go and how do I bring it back?
Did I make a mistake?
And do you have any guides for me to help me start with Ubuntu?

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
So apparently the external hard drive is still "there" somewhere.
I managed to install testdisk and it showed me that the hard drive is still there and testdisk can still see it.
However, it doesn't show in my file manager.

Here what happens when I write sudo df -h:

```
gabriel@GABRI:~$ sudo df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1,6G  9,4M  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/sda2       213G  4,8G  198G   3% /
tmpfs           7,9G  1,7M  7,9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7,9G     0  7,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       511M  3,5M  508M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1,6G   92K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb2       2,0G  1,2G  914M  56% /media/gabriel/HI-TECH Treiber
```

Edit:
I plugged my external hard drive out and in again and now nothing recognizes it anymore not even testdisk
Help??

[image]

So as I still see that this post is getting commented, I just want to tell you that I already solved the problem.
You can read how I did it [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58058/discussion-on-question-by-g-sarkap-i-formatted-my-external-drive).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58058/discussion-on-question-by-g-sarkap-i-formatted-my-external-drive).

Comment: What's the output of `sudo lsblk -f`? By the way, you don't need super-user privileges to run `df`. File system statistics are viewable by everybody in Ubuntu.

Comment: If "nothing" detects your external hard drive, There are number of possible problems. To help us narrow it down, please provide further information such as how the drive is connected (USB perhaps, Firewire)?